# Any better alternative for WSUS report?

Tags: wsus

I am using WSUS server on Server2012R2. The reporting function is really painful.

Sometimes I only need to have a simple report to see if a specific KB is installed or not on a list of computers from an OU. But WSUS report just wont gives you that simple answer.

Is there a better solution / software can generate the report for that?

Comment: I also agree that reporting functionality in WSUS (at least on Server 2012 R2) is terrible! In my organisation, we're having SQL Server Standard installed to store WSUS Database related information; we rely only on SQL queries to identify which all updates are installed/failed/pending-reboot, etc. for a particular IP or a hostname!

Comment: What do you use for getting information from WSUS into SQL server?

Comment: While installing WSUS Role, it asks for type of installation of database where WSUS will store client data. So, you can select SQL Server as database for storing WSUS Data.

Comment: I remember I saw that option when I install WSUS.....but I chose local database instead of our sql cluster....I think it is too late now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [TechNet's Choose the Database Used for WSUS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708452(v=ws.10).aspx)

> The WSUS database stores the following types of information:

1. WSUS server configuration information
2. Metadata that describes each update
3. Information about client computers, updates, and client interaction with updates

> Selecting a database

1. Windows Internal Database ships with WSUS. This version of SQL Server does not have a user interface or tools. Administrators are meant to interact with these products through WSUS.
2. Microsoft SQL Server is the full-featured database software from Microsoft. WSUS requires SQL Server. If you use the full version of SQL Server, the SQL Server administrator should enable the nested triggers option in SQL Server.

Do this before the WSUS administrator installs WSUS and specifies the database during the setup process. WSUS Setup enables the recursive triggers option, which is a database-specific option; however, it does not enable the nested triggers option, which is a server global option.

---

**SUGGESTED SOLUTION (if you opt SQL Server as Database):**

Once you've moved to SQL Server database for installing WSUS data, you can fire your own SQL queries on the `SUSDB` database which is created by WSUS.

There are several tables and views in WSUS which you can query to get the relevant details.

[image: Sample Tables in WSUS' SUSDB database]

Sample query for getting the list of all Windows Updates installed in a particular system:

```
select tbct1.IPAddress, tbct1.FullDomainName, tbct1.LastReportedRebootTime,vu.DefaultTitle
 from SUSDB.dbo.tbUpdateStatusPerComputer AS tbuspc,
          SUSDB.dbo.tbUpdate AS tbu ,
           SUSDB.dbo.tbComputerTarget AS tbct1 ,
          SUSDB.PUBLIC_VIEWS.vUpdate AS vu ,
          SUSDB.PUBLIC_VIEWS.vUpdateAdditionalInfoUrl AS vuaiu
            where tbuspc.SummarizationState in (4) and ipAddress like '<system-ip>'
             and tbuspc.LocalUpdateID = tbu.LocalUpdateID 
            and tbuspc.TargetID = tbct1.TargetID
            and tbu.UpdateID = vu.UpdateId
            and  vu.UpdateId = vuaiu.UpdateId 
            and vuaiu.LocaleId='1033';
-- here SummarizationState 4 means installed.
-- you can search on the web for different possible SummarizationStates in WSUS.
```

Comment: Is there a way to move DB from WSUS to SQL database after WSUS installed?

Comment: @RootLoop - Yes, you can migrate your database from WID to SQL Server. Check this documentation from Microsoft -> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-server-update-services/manage/wid-to-sql-migration

Comment: Wonderful. I will try this.